# Is there an abstract state in Angular2 Router?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm looking for similar solution to [ui-router abstract state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/nested-states-%26-nested-views#abstract-states) in Angular2 Router.

To have "*virtual*" parent state to resolve some common things for child states.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A route doesn't need to be associated with a component. It can just have children with an empty path. You can use this "empty" route for things like guards or resolves.

One thing I didn't know until testing right now, is that [`Resolve`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Resolve-interface.html)s (it's data) will trickle down to child routes. So if you want to "resolve some common things for child states", this might be the place to do it.

```
{
  path: '',
  resolve: {
    data: DummyResolve
  },
  children: [
    { path: 'one', component: Child1Component },
    { path: 'two', component: Child2Component }
  ]
}
```

Here is the complete test I used to test with

```
import { Component, Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Resolve, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Location, CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { TestBed, inject, fakeAsync, tick, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';

@Injectable()
class DummyResolve implements Resolve<string> {
  resolve() {
    return 'Hello Routing';
  }
}

@Component({
  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
class RoutingComponent {
}

@Component({
  template: `
    <h1>Child One</h1>
    <span>{{ data }}</span>
  `
})
class Child1Component implements OnInit {
  data: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.forEach((data: { data: string }) => {
      this.data = data.data;
      console.log(`data from child 1: ${this.data}`);
    });
  }
}

@Component({
  template: `
    <h1>Child Two</h1>
    <span>{{ data }}</span>
  `
})
class Child2Component implements OnInit {
  data: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.forEach((data: { data: string }) => {
      this.data = data.data;
      console.log(`data from child 2: ${this.data}`);
    });
  }
}

describe('component: RoutingComponent', function () {
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<RoutingComponent>;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([
          {
            path: '',
            resolve: {
              data: DummyResolve
            },
            children: [
              { path: 'one', component: Child1Component },
              { path: 'two', component: Child2Component }
            ]
          }
        ])
      ],
      providers: [ DummyResolve ],
      declarations: [ RoutingComponent, Child1Component, Child2Component ]
    });

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(RoutingComponent);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should go to child one',
    fakeAsync(inject([Router, Location], (router: Router, location: Location) => {

    router.navigate(['/one']);
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let debugEl = fixture.debugElement;
    expect(debugEl.query(By.css('h1')).nativeElement.innerHTML).toEqual('Child One');
    expect(debugEl.query(By.css('span')).nativeElement.innerHTML).toEqual('Hello Routing');
  })));

  it('should go to child two',
    fakeAsync(inject([Router, Location], (router: Router, location: Location) => {

    router.navigate(['/two']);
    tick();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    let debugEl = fixture.debugElement;
    expect(debugEl.query(By.css('h1')).nativeElement.innerHTML).toEqual('Child Two');
    expect(debugEl.query(By.css('span')).nativeElement.innerHTML).toEqual('Hello Routing');
  })));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add child route like this [app.routeing.ts]

```
const APP_ROUTES:Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/dashboard', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'report', component: ReportComponent, children: REPORT_ROUTES},
  ];
```

and child route would be

```
export const REPORT_ROUTES: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', component: ReportHomeComponent },
  { path: 'server-report', component: ServerReportComponent } //  report/server-report
  { path: 'client-report', component: ClientReportComponent }  //  report/client-report
];
```

Comment: I would like to do some manipulations with common data on abstract state and not only redirect

Comment: you can do on child component [templateUrl] of component meta data